# What commentators follow approach of Remez

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, commentaries, pardes

I mean, could you please name some commentators on the Torah?
For example:
Pshat (Rashi, Rashbam, Radak, Ibn Ezra).

Comment: Can you define what you mean by "remez"?

Comment: Remez (רֶמֶז‎) – "hints" or the deep (allegoric: hidden or symbolic) meaning beyond just the literal sense

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Alshich.
2. Vilna Gaon to Esther.
3. Ohr Hachaim.
4. Rabbeinu Bechaye in part.
5. Maharam MiRotenburg.

Comment: Where is the maharam on Torah?

Comment: It's published in the Toras Chaim edition of Mikraos Gedolos.

Answer (score 6):

1. Baal Haturim
2. Rokeach
3. Rabeinu Ephraim

These are amongst the reishonim that are into remazim.

Answer (score 1):

1. Chasam Sofer (Toras Moshe)
2. Medrash Rabbah
3. Medrash Tanchuma

(In no particular order...)

Comment: I don't think these have anything to do with remez.